# Mockito thenAnswer not being called

Tags: sockets, callback, mocking, mockito

I am testing the interaction with a socket
I have mocked the socket, and want to test that something happened in the ack, for that I need to have the ack called.

I tried to write the following :

```
        Answer<Void> answer = invocation -> {
            Ack ack = invocation.getArgument(2);
            ack.call(any(Object[].class));
            return null;
        };
        doAnswer(answer).when(socket).emit(anyString(),any(Object[].class),any(Ack.class));
```

However, when in my code, my mock socket does `socket.emit("blahblah","bababa",Ack);`

The answer is not invoked.

How to make it work ?

Comment: According to the mock expectation, the second argument to `emit` is an `Object[]` (see: `any(Object[].class`) but in your post you state: _my mock socket does socket.emit("blahblah","bababa",Ack);_ so you pass a String. This will not match with the `Object[]` expectation.

Comment: this is correct, I had wrong signature, put this as an answer, I will accept

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the mock expectation, the second argument to emit is an `Object[]` ...

```
doAnswer(answer).when(socket).emit(anyString(),any(Object[].class),any(Ack.class));
```

See: `any(Object[].class)`

But in your post you state:

> my mock socket does socket.emit("blahblah","bababa",Ack);

So you pass a String (`"bababa"`) for the second parameter. This will not match with the `Object[]` expectation.

If you change your mock expectation to ...

```
doAnswer(answer).when(socket).emit(anyString(), anyString(), any(Ack.class));
```

... then the invocation should match.